# Insert value under specific node

Tags: xml, powershell

I am attempting to use powershell to manipulate Firefox mimeTypes.rdf for all existing user Firefox profiles.

**I want to add the following entry**

```xml
<RDF:li RDF:resource="urn:mimetype:application/x-zip-compressed"/>
```

**Specifically under:**

```xml
<RDF:Seq RDF:about="urn:mimetypes:root">
```

As per guide at http://kb.mozillazine.org/MimeTypes.rdf. I have worked out appending InnerXml from a reference XML doc to update RDF:Description nodes, but the RDF:Seq direct entry eludes me.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RDF:RDF xmlns:NC="http://home.netscape.com/NC-rdf#"         xmlns:RDF="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
  <RDF:Seq RDF:about="urn:schemes:root">
    <RDF:li RDF:resource="urn:scheme:webcal"/>
    <RDF:li RDF:resource="urn:scheme:ircs"/>
    <RDF:li RDF:resource="urn:scheme:mailto"/>
    <RDF:li RDF:resource="urn:scheme:irc"/>
  </RDF:Seq>
  <RDF:Seq RDF:about="urn:mimetypes:root">
    <RDF:li RDF:resource="urn:mimetype:application/x-ica"/>
  </RDF:Seq>
 </RDF:RDF>
```

A number of approaches have been tried:

```bsh
[xml]$s = (Select-Xml -Path .\seq.rdf -XPath / ).node
$xpathquery  = "/RDF:RDF[@xmlns:NC=`"http://home.netscape.com/NC-rdf#`"]/RDF:Seq[@RDF:about=`"urn:mimetypes:root`"]/RDF:li"
$nsmgr = $s.NameTable
$nsmgr.AddNamespace('NC',"http://home.netscape.com/NC-rdf#")
$nsmgr.AddNamespace('RDF',"http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" )

Select-Xml -Xml $s -XPath $xpathquery -Namespace $nsmgr
```

And then using `AppendChild()`/`CreateElement()` methods

```bsh
$child = $s.CreateElement
AppendChild($child)
```

And then using `AppendChild()` various ways:

```bsh
$null = $s.RDF.seq.Where{
            ($_.About -match 'urn:mimetype:application')
        }.Component.AppendChild($child)
```

Or `ImportNode()` from a reference file:

```bsh
foreach ($Node in $a.RDF.Seq.ChildNodes) {
    ($xc.DocumentElement.AppendChild($s.ImportNode($a.RDF.Seq.ChildNodes, $true)))
    #$xc.DocumentElement.Description.SetAttribute("description", "Config file for testing")
}
```

As you can see I'm confused here without a solid grasp of manipulating XML. Part of the problem is the XPath query (if it is needed).

Answer (score 1):

I'd tried to recreate your task and have this as solution:

```
[xml]$a=Get-Content "C:\temp\XML.xml"
#clone first about node
$b=($a.rdf.seq|where {$_.about -eq "urn:mimetypes:root"}).li.clone()
#modify the cloned node
$b.resource="urn:mimetype:application/x-zip-compressed"
#add modified node to xml
($a.rdf.seq|where {$_.about -eq "urn:mimetypes:root"}).AppendChild($b)

#save in new file
$a.Save("C:\temp\XML-Updated.xml")
```

And the result is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RDF:RDF xmlns:NC="http://home.netscape.com/NC-rdf#" xmlns:RDF="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
  <RDF:Seq RDF:about="urn:schemes:root">
    <RDF:li RDF:resource="urn:scheme:webcal" />
    <RDF:li RDF:resource="urn:scheme:ircs" />
    <RDF:li RDF:resource="urn:scheme:mailto" />
    <RDF:li RDF:resource="urn:scheme:irc" />
  </RDF:Seq>
  <RDF:Seq RDF:about="urn:mimetypes:root">
    <RDF:li RDF:resource="urn:mimetype:application/x-ica" />
    <RDF:li RDF:resource="urn:mimetype:application/x-zip-compressed" />
  </RDF:Seq>
</RDF:RDF>
```

I don't have time to digging now, but hope that this can help you

Answer (score 1):

Assigning a name table to a variable doesn't magically create a namespace manager. You need to instantiate a namespace manager and initialize it with the name table:

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\your.xml'
$nsm = New-Object Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($xml.NameTable)
```

Otherwise the `AddNamespace()` calls would throw errors.

Then you create and append the new elements, e.g. from the inside out:

1. Create an `RDF:resource` attribute and assign the value to the attribute.
2. Create an `RDF:li` node and append the attribute to the node's attributes.
3. Select the node to which you want to append the new node and append it.

```bsh
$NC_NS  = 'http://home.netscape.com/NC-rdf#'
$RDF_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#'

[xml]$xml = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\input.xml'
$nsm = New-Object Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($xml.NameTable)
$nsm.AddNamespace('NC', $NC_NS)
$nsm.AddNamespace('RDF', $RDF_NS)

$attr = $xml.CreateAttribute('RDF', 'resource', $RDF_NS)
$attr.Value = 'urn:mimetype:application/x-zip-compressed'

$node = $xml.CreateElement('RDF', 'li', $RDF_NS)
$node.Attributes.Append($attr) | Out-Null

$parent = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//RDF:Seq[@RDF:about='urn:mimetypes:root']", $nsm)
$parent.AppendChild($node) | Out-Null

xml.Save('C:\path\to\output.xml')
```